# Sometimes 8.8.8.8 does not find our domain

Tags: google, resolve, google-public-dns

When resolving towards 8.8.8.8 from a local wi-fi or a personal hotspot, etc. it sometimes fails.
Responses are received from these Google IP addresses:

```
74.125.46.10
74.125.112.1
74.125.112.9
74.125.x.x
74.125.z.z
74.125.w.w
```

But when resolving towards 8.8.8.8 from a server on AWS or DO it always succeeds.
The responses are received from different Google IP addresses:

```
172.253.199.4
172.253.1.194
172.217.33.132
```

**Why is it so?**

An idea: Does Google give a higher priority for big customers like AWS or DO vs the public...? Or is there a different explanation?

---

Additionally:

1. We even made a test subdomain xip.teltel.io which is set up exactly the same way and when resolving that domain towards 8.8.8.8 it works fine every time.
   The only difference between sip.teltel.io and xip.teltel.io is the load:
   sip receives our customer's traffic and xip only our test requests.

**How can you explain that?**

--

2. We captured the traffic by performing a tcpdump (tcpdump udp and port 53) and noticed that when Google fails to resolve, our name servers never receive a request from Google.

--

3. Here you can test the loops for yourself:
   This fails with "sip"  - while true; do dig A 42894078.sip.teltel.io @8.8.8.8; done;
   This is OK with "xip"- while true; do dig A 42894078.xip.teltel.io @8.8.8.8; done;

---

Please, can you help us solve this? It seems quite mysterious to us.

Thanks!

Comment: Google will actually tell you about the difference in a human-readable comment for [both](https://dns.google.com/query?name=42894078.xip.teltel.io&rr_type=NS) [queries](https://dns.google.com/query?name=42894078.sip.teltel.io&rr_type=NS) if you use the web site.

Comment: Observation: `ns1.teltel.io` and `ns2.teltel.io` only resolve in Ipv4.. both to `3.9.142.25`

Comment: In addition to still using only a single name server have you addressed any of the other issues raised in the previous answers you got when asking about this issue ?

Comment: @HermanB we made all the changes that were noted.